# hibernate dynamic-update and insert using annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Since `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true,dynamicInsert=true)` is deprecated, tried using `@DynamicInsert`, `@DynamicUpdate`  but it seems not working for me. 
can you suggest me any solution for dynamic update and insert using hibernate annotation.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: hibernate-annotations 3.5.6-Final,hibernate-commons-annotations 3.2.0.Final,hibernate-core 4.1.4.Final,hibernate 3.5.4-Final

Answer (score 0):

Please use,

@DynamicUpdate

combination, for 4.1.X version onward. Earlier, Entity based directives are deprecated. If session is not reused, add,

@SelectBeforeUpdate

also.

I can't be sure about all the 4.1 versions, but 4.1.4 and higher will surely work fine.